# Problems Installing Display Link on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kernel, displaylink

Hello im having problems trying to install display link on Ubuntu.
Im using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ,Kernel Linux 5.4.0-40-generic

Here are the instructions im trying to follow.
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0

And this is what happened.

As soon as i tried to run this command
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.3.0.xx.run

This was my result.
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.3.0.xx.run: command not found

then i tried to change 5.3.0.xx to reflect my current Kernel version and i got the same result. which was this

sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0.40.run: command not found

Im stuck right here.

Comment: Open the folder where it's extracted in the terminal and it's then *sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run* (for the current version - I just downloaded it and checked and that's the version available right this minute). Change the version # to be the version # that you have. Use copy/paste if it helps.

Comment: i tried that and this is what happened

:~/Downloads/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 5.3.1$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run 
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run: command not found

Comment: I got it for you... First *chmod +x ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run* and then run the command. You have to make it executable.

Comment: this is what happened next 

:~/Downloads/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 5.3.1$ chmod +x ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run 
/Downloads/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 5.3.1$ sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run

Command 'sudo:' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sudo' from deb sudo (1.8.31-1ubuntu1)
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo-ldap (1.8.31-1ubuntu1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Comment: Are you typing that colon? There's no colon. It's just "sudo" without any punctuation.

Comment: hey thanks  i took out the colon and now it worked. 

now this is where i'm at.  seems to be taking a while though

Package configuration

 ┌────────────────────────┤ Configuring Secure Boot ├────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                   
 │                                                     
 │

Answer (score 2):

To run the file, you first must make it executable.

Extract the file and then open the containing folder in your terminal. Run:

```
chmod +x ./displaylink-driver-5.3.x.x.run
```

(Change the name to match the file downloaded.)

Then just run the file from the terminal with:

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.3.x.x.run
```

(Again changing the name to match the file downloaded.)

Enter your password as requested and follow the on-screen prompts.